# How to import multiple dump files to mysql in windows?

Tags: mysql, database, windows, import, dump

I need to import multiple dump files to mysql using windows command prompt.

How can I import files.

`mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -proot -P3306 --databases db1,db2<db1.sql,db2.sql`

I tried like this but its not working. How can i write this kind of a command in a bat file.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Import Several .sql files at once into a mysql Database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000147/how-to-import-several-sql-files-at-once-into-a-mysql-database)

Answer (score -1):

use two commands (and I don't think there is a --databases option in mysql, are you confusing that with mysqldump?).

```
mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -proot -P3306 db1 < db1.sql
mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -proot -P3306  db2 < db2.sql
```

Comment: Hi its creating only second database :(

Comment: do you get an error? is there a "create database" statement in your db1.sql?

Comment: yes I have. if I execute that bat file its not showing db1.sql. Do we need to give any separation between that two satements

Comment: hmm.. I don't see a reason why the 2nd statement would be executed but not the first.it's been a while since I've done scripting on windows, maybe someone else has an idea.