# How to setup a MySQL server for a GitHub Workflow and run a SQL script?

Tags: mysql, docker, github-actions

I have a GitHub workflow file with a mysql job: Runs on ubuntu-latest, has a Docker container with the mysql:8 image, and port 33306:3306. Then I added a step which runs the `mysql --protocol=tcp -h localhost --port 33306 -uroot -ppassword -e "$(cat $(find -wholename ./sql/init.sql))"` command, but that returns the following error: `ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 2`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more straight forward way is to, cat the file first and then pipe them to MySQL prompt like below.

```
cat $(find -wholename ./sql/init.sql) | mysql --protocol=tcp -hlocalhost --port 33306 -uroot -ppassword
```

or use a < symbol to redirect your file to mysql

```
mysql --protocol=tcp -h localhost --port 33306 -uroot -ppassword < ./sql/init.sql
```

If this also not works, then you have a problem in your file, somethings MySQL won't explicitly mention in their error messages! could be a character set problem.

This [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000147/how-to-easily-import-multiple-sql-files-into-a-mysql-database) helps if you have a collection of files to execute:

Comment: It seems the error was indeed caused by the character set, it's fixed now. Thanks! :D